# Does O(f(n)) + O(g(n)) = O(max{f(n), g(n)})?

Tags: asymptotics

A question from a lecture of mine.
The way I see it, while summing sets is meaningless, O(f(n)) + O(g(n)) is obviously limited from above by the greatest function in either, which means that I practically take the maximum of O(f(n)) and the maximum O(g(n)), and claim that either is the maximal one, or they are equal.

Would this be a legitimate claim in an exam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to read this "identity" is as follows:

> If $a = O(f(n))$ and $b = O(g(n))$ then $a+b = O(\max\{f(n),g(n)\})$.

This indeed holds, as you can prove using the definition of big O.

There is another possible interpretation:

> $\{ a + b : a = O(f(n)), \; b = O(g(n)) \} = \{ c : c = O(\max\{f(n),g(n)\})\}$.

This also holds, as you van prove using the definition.

Whether it is a *legitimate claim in an exam* is up to your professor. It is definitely a legitimate claim in a paper.